# dd_roundies rounded corners in IE7 messed up on window resize

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer-7, doctype, rounded-corners

**Here is a quick example:**  http://goo.gl/zkyqM

if DOCTYPE is

`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`

Everytime I *Restore/Maximize* the window on IE7 The rounded DIVS are not repainted and will not move with the layout.

---

If I change my DOCTYPE to

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

Everytime I *Resize* the window on IE7 the rounded DIVS do are again not repainted and will not move with the layout.

---

If I change my DOCTYPE to

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN">`

There will be no rounded corners

Any ideas how to make dd_roundies work well on all browsers? as it claims to be. Or, if you have other suggestions on rendering round corners in IE please tell me.

> IE6 -> OK
>
> Firefox -> OK
>
> Chrome -> OK
>
> > IE7 -> Not OK

Comment: providing your html-css code or even better a live example at http://jsbin.com would help more. Also `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">` I think is required when you define `DOCTYPE` for XHTML 1.0 :)

Comment: Hi, I do have `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">` that on my project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [CSS3PIE](http://css3pie.com/documentation/product-comparison/)

Comment: This is not really an answer. I will change the accepted answer, if someone has a better answer. I also have problems with CSS3PIE on nested rounded divs in IE upon hover divs elements move.